# post picture/video to a php server on google glass

Tags: java, android, google-glass

Is there any way to upload a photo that I took (by the "take a picture" voice command)/ a video (by the "record a video" command) of the google glass to a php server?

Comment: we need a lot more detail of your problems - what have you tried? What do you mean by a php server? Are you developing a Google Glass App?

Comment: Yes, I'm a google glass developer. Php server means a php file to this context. I'm trying to do the next thing: let's say I'm taking a photo with the following intent: Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST);            I want to locate the picture I just did in the glass drive so I can upload it to a server.

Answer (score 0):

The common paradigm for photos that are taken with "take a picture" and "record a video" is to then let the user share them to a contact. That contact can be created and managed by a PHP server and can be on the receiving end of the media item being sent. This wouldn't involve any Java/Android code at all on your end.

Take a look at information about [the Mirror API](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/index). In particular, you will want to setup a [Contact](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/contacts) and subscribe to responses for the same.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a way to upload to a php server an image that has been taken by the intent ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE without Mirror API. The flow is that: I take a picture, this pic is saved into the filesystem of the google glass. I want to be able to access this location and the pic name that was generated and upload it. All of this via code in Java/Android.